# How to run an ActiveJob only once in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

Im using subscriptions and plans in my application together with Stripe. My Plan entity has a lot of "visual" data on the model and is related with the payment gateway sharing a identifier.

I have already a migration that generates my basic plan data. Like this:

```
class CreateBasicPlanData < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    Plan.create(name:'Hobby', 
    visibility: 'Low Visibility',
    card_description:'Free portfolio listing good for beginners.',
    features_description:'<ul><li>5 Portfolio Images</li><li>Messaging to other Talent</li><li>Basic Search Ranking</li></ul>',
    price: 0,
    css:'plan-hobby',
    number_albums: 1,
    number_photos_per_album: 5,
    payment_gateway_plan_identifier: 'hobby'
    )

    Plan.create(name:'Professional', card_description:'Solid portfolio for those wanting more exposure and booking opportunities.',
    visibility: 'High Visibility',
    features_description:'<strong>Everything included in Hobby <em>PLUS:</em></strong><ul><li>25 Portfolio Images</li><li>Intermediate Search Ranking</li><li>Multi-state portfolio listing</li></ul>',
    price: 4.99,
    css:'plan-professional',
    number_albums: 5,
    number_photos_per_album: 25,
    payment_gateway_plan_identifier: 'professional'
    )
```

I want to create a Job that, when the system is ok, get all the data from my local database, and create the Stripe Plans. My code is something like that:

```
class SyncLocalPlansWithStripe < ActiveJob::Base
def perform
    plans = Plan.all
    #delete all the plans on stripe
     Plan.transaction do
      begin 
        puts 'Start deleting'
        Stripe::Plan.list.each do |plan_to_delete|
          plan_to_delete.delete
        end
        puts 'End deleting'
      end
    end
    Plan.transaction do
      begin 
        plans.each do |plan| 
          PaymentGateway::CreatePlanService.new(plan).run 
        end
      rescue PaymentGateway::CreatePlanServiceError => e
        puts "Error message: #{e.message}"
        puts "Exception message: #{e.exception_message}"
      end
    end
  end
```

My question is. How can I run this Job, when I want, only once, from the console?

Something like rake:job run sync_local_plans_with_stripe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are confusing rake tasks with ActiveJob.

If you want to run a job from within `rails console` you can just execute `SyncLocalPlansWithStripe.perform_now`. See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#enqueue-the-job

As suggested in the comments you can also run the job directly from the command line using Rails runner: `rails runner "SyncLocalPlansWithStripe.perform_now"`

Or if you'd rather run this as a rake task then you'll need to create one for this instead. See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#custom-rake-tasks

Comment: Also, you could use the rails runner command instead of the console if you want a one-liner: `rails runner "SyncLocalPlansWithStripe.perform_now"` (and you can specify an environment with the `-e <environment name>` option).